# Updating visited status of a link when changing its href attribute, under Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, hyperlink, safari

When I am updating links with JavaScript

```
$('#link_id').attr('href', some_new_url)
```

the color theme for visited/non-visited links persists, regardless of the status of the new url address.

Is there a way to change link address forcing browser to re-check its visited status?

Further notes:

I am (on OSX 10.8) experiencing this problem in Chrome (32) and Safari (6.1). In Firefox (26) the links status gets updated automatically, as desired.

The example above is in jQuery, but the problem is the same way with with vanilla JavaScript, i.e. `document.getElementById` and `setAttribute`.

(I would prefer to avoid deleting and adding `<a></a>`, if possible.)

EDIT:

Minimal (non-)working example (by Joeytje50): http://jsfiddle.net/3pdVW/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand  your request. Are you wanting to target styling of visited links so every link is always the same colour, regardless of visited status?

Comment: It works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3pdVW/ (Chrome 32, Win7). Could you provide an example JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem you're having?

Comment: @Adrian Yes. I mean, if the previous link was visited, the new will have colour of visited link. If the previous was not visited - of not visited. And it does not depend on the status of the new link address.

Comment: @Joeytje50 On Chrome it does not work. Under Firefox is does. Under Safari if does not. (Exactly as previously. Thx though for minimal (not) working example.)

Comment: What I'd like to know is: why are you doing this in this particular way? Also what exactly are you doing? Are you having a single link tag on the page and swapping out the href? For what reason? What does the link do, and why wouldn't you just use a templating system of some kind to swap out the HTML for the section in which the link resides?

Comment: @Adrian There are many links, and they go to various pages. Or maybe it is easier to show than to describe: http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/ (disclaimer: work in progress and the underlying code is ugly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Definitive answer

What you could do to fix this, is simply forcing the browser to recalculate the styles by completely removing the `href` attribute, and then re-adding it back again immediately afterwards. That will make the browser first calculate the styles, since the `<a>` is no longer a link without the `href`, and then you add the `href` you want to give it. The code would then be:

```
$('#link_id').removeAttr('href').prop('href', some_new_url);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3pdVW/5/)

PS: in this case, using `.attr('href', some_new_url);` would probably work equally fine.

## Previous attempts

What I'm thinking is that this is a rendering glitch. It doesn't recalculate the styles when the `:visited` state changes because of the script. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/3pdVW/) minimal example of your problem shows this well. What you could try is either of the following:

### Using the element's properties

What the problem might be is that you're changing the attribute, which in turn changes the href property. If you directly change the href property it might work. You can do this via [jQuery.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), which would use the following code to change the link:

```
$('#link_id').prop('href', some_new_url);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3pdVW/1/). I don't really have very high hopes about this one, but it's worth trying. What I do suspect will work much better is:

### Forcing to recalculate the styles

If you want to force a recalculation of the styles, you can simply change a class on the highest element you want updated. Since you're updating the `<a>` element alone, you'd need something like this:

```
$('#link_id').prop('href', some_new_url).toggleClass('webkit-force-recalculate');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3pdVW/2/)

I think that is quite likely to do the trick.

---

If neither of these approaches work for you, you could of course use [maximgladkov's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21892256/1256925).

Comment: Neither solves the problem, neither for Chrome nor Safari, at my computer. Thanks for examples, though!

Comment: @PiotrMigdal could you try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3pdVW/3/), which toggles a class on the body instead, and see if it works?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. (As a side note, if it is not a general problem, I am curious why it happens and how is it common (well, I care more for viewers than rendering on my machine.).)

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I've edited my answer to include a definitive answer at the top. If this doesn't work, then I am not sure anything will, but then again, I'm quite convinced this should work. Good luck with your code!

Comment: The answer on the top, i.e. `.removeAttr('href').prop('href', some_new_url)` works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change it like this:

```
$('#link_id').replaceWith($('<a href="' + some_new_url +'">' + $('#link_id').text() + '</a>'));
```

It should do the trick. Tested: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/L3LMd/

Comment: "(I would prefer to avoid deleting and adding <a></a>, if possible.)" --OP. This is an alternative OP was not looking for, even if it works.

Comment: @Joeytje50 I prefer, not demand. :) If not possible I will go with it.

Comment: It's not possible without it. Period.

Comment: It's possible without it. All you need to do is to force a reflow, as other have answerd. My favourite way is simply calling `$('.elem').height()`

Comment: Replacing do work; `$('.elem').height()` does not work (at least on my computer). Though, answer by user13500 works, and is without replacing.

Answer (score 1):

Frequently experience similar issues, e.g. when setting size of elements with border, there are stray borders left etc.

Though this is not directly the same, I have found that hiding the element does the trick. Have not had any trouble with it.

#### [Simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/hKr73/)

```
$("#change_link").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#anchor1").hide();
    $("#anchor1").attr('href', $("#url").val());
    $("#anchor1").show();
});
```

This should force a redraw of the element.

Comment: Works! (Both under Chrome and Safari.)

Comment: (I cannot accept two answers, so I give bounty to yours!)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is the following CSS code:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00F;
}
a:visited {
    color: #00F;
}
```

Comment: I do want to have different colors. Of course, I can mask the problem, but it is not the goal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you update your question to be more clear about your requirements and an example use case? Because your question sounds like you just don't want the visited links to have the browser-default visited link colour.