# how to change active link color without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to develop a website. My site has two navigation link. When user  click on the navigation link then page will be load without refresh. I have done this part. But problem is , color of the active link is not changing. This is my site https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/168659703/project3/index.html and i have used the following code for page load

```
 $(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wra"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$(".nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);


    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });

                    $(".nav a").removeClass("active");
                    $(".nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("active");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Please tell me How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You can set a class to have the desired colour and add the class to the anchor you clicked on or modify the link colour with jquery

Comment: Won't the _href_ start with a hash `#`, but you cut this out of `newHash`? So you need to add it back into your selector where you're adding the class.

Answer (score 0):

If I read you correctly you need to reset the anchor:

```
$("#anchor1").hide();
$("#anchor1").attr('href', some_val);
$("#anchor1").show();
```

Or

```
var href = $('#anchor1').attr("href")
$('#anchor1').removeAttr('href').prop('href', href);
```

Or the like.

Point being to force browser to repaint element.

[Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21838836/3278057)

Answer (score 0):

Change colour directly

```
$(".nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).css('color', '#000'); // black for example
    return false;
});
```

or by adding a class

```
$(".nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).addClass('visited');
    return false;
});
```

CSS

```
.visited {
    color: #000;
}
```